# How to create a group by spliting the dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
 df:
 order             quantity
  A                   1
  B                   1
  C                   2
  D                   3
  E                   3
  F                   4
```

My goal is to create a group from this Dataframe based on the Quantity value.
My desired result.

```
 df:
group        order             quantity
  1             A                   1
                B                   1
                C                   2
  2             D                   3
                E                   1
  3             E                   2
                F                   2
  4             F                   2
```

So here my desired result is based on quantity. Max value of quantity is 4.
In `group1`, `group2` &`group3` the total values (A+B+C=4)(i.e keeping the max vale of  quantity  as 4).
In `group4`  we can see that no values to add so the group is formed by the left over(here it is 2).
In `group2`&`group3` you can see the value of E and F are divided.

So in future I can select the group by its name or number.

Note:
My actual order`(column["order"])` looks like this `"PMC11-AA1L1PAVWJJ+Z1"`
its a string.

Is this possible in python. If so kindly suggest me the method. I could practice and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],'quantity':[1,1,2,3,3,4]})
```

Solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
                  columns=['order'])
df['quantity'] = 1
df['group'] = sorted(range(0, len(df)/3, 1) * 4)[0:len(df)]
```

Output:

```
   order  quantity  group
0      A         1      0
1      B         1      0
2      C         1      0
3      C         1      0
4      D         1      1
5      D         1      1
6      D         1      1
7      E         1      1
8      E         1      2
9      E         1      2
10     F         1      2
11     F         1      2
12     F         1      3
13     F         1      3
```

Then groupby and sum.

```
df.groupby(['group', 'order']).sum()
```

Output:

```
             quantity
group order          
0     A             1
      B             1
      C             2
1     D             3
      E             1
2     E             2
      F             2
3     F             2
```

You can use reset_index() after that, if you want.

I hope it helps.

Should I explain the solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, But I am getting an error. Type error: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. `df['group'] = sorted(range(0, len(df)/3, 1) * 4)[0:len(df)]` Can u tell me why?

Comment: @user10309160 Try to change this raw. df['group'] = sorted(range(0, int(len(df)/3), 1) * 4)[0:len(df)]

Comment: Hi, now it showing value error:int() base must be >=2 and <=36,or 0. I don't know whether I made any mistake. I have values all less than or equal to 4 in `df['quantity]`

Comment: @user10309160 it's really strange, I don't have errors. Try just  `df['group'] = sorted(range(0, len(df)) * 4)[0:len(df)]`

Comment: again a `type error: unsupported operator types for *: 'range' and 'int'`

Comment: Can u explain what have u done in df['group']. So that I could understand and try to find the problem

Comment: @user10309160 just an array like `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5]` to number a group. I add an example `df` before `groupby` and `sum`.

Comment: Okay. no problem in that. Really strange. I could not find why its showing error.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I have extracted my df from a huge dataframe. I tried to print in the excel . so in Column A has the row values from where it has been extracted and column B and Chas my df. so `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
                  columns=['order'])
` I have to change x[0] to x[1] and x[1] to x[2]. is that ryt?

Comment: nope.its crazy. `IndexError: ('index out of bound' , 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia Great approach! +1

Comment: I think I have found the problem .  because I have extracted from other df. My index value is different. say  index for `A`=`0`, `B`=`13`,`C`=`102`. How to reset this index which is derived from other dataframe . So that I could perform your function

Comment: @user10309160 try `df = df.reset_index().drop(['index'], 1)`

Comment: that resets my index. I have a question If my `column["order"]` has Strings like `"PTP31B-AA4M1PGBWWJ"` this. would the above code works?

Answer (score 2):

@AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia solution is awesome.  I re-wrote it using pure pandas.

```
#Generate input dataframe from @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia
df = pd.DataFrame({'order':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],'quantity':[1,1,2,3,3,4]})
#Expand dataframe 
df_out = df.order.repeat(df.quantity).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
#Create groupings of four records 
df_out['grp'] = df_out.index // 4
#Groupby 'grp' and count
df_out.groupby(['grp','order'])['order'].count().to_frame(name='quantity')
```

Output:

```
           quantity
grp order          
0   A             1
    B             1
    C             2
1   D             3
    E             1
2   E             2
    F             2
3   F             2
```

Comment: Thanks, both are very good method. I know there is no problem from your side. but there is something wrong in my data because I have extracted the data from a huge dataFrame. When using your code I received `TypeError: cannot cast array data from dtype('0') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: I have a question If my column["order"] has Strings like "PTP31B-AA4M1PGBWWJ" instead of `A,B`. would the above code works?

Comment: @user10309160 Yes, it would it.